# Low level explaination of executable binary formats used in Windows and linux

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, format, executable

I've come across many programming languages. Each of them had their charm, but also a few things I disliked. Therefore I'm designing my own programming language and simply implement the things I liked in other languages.

After doing some of research, though mostly speculation, I believe I somewhat understand how processors and operating systems work. I managed to make an interpreter which reads and interprets instructions in a custom format I made using an instruction pointer and some (virtual) registers, and have been compiling code to that format for now.

However, this seems silly to me as my compiler now generates a binary to generate a binary and interpret it, and then interprets that. Though the current way of doing it does have some benefits (such as compiling just once and being able to run it *almost* everywhere), I'm curious about where to start when making a compiler that actually generates code the operating system can read.

I heard some things about PE and ELF, but have not been able to find anything that describes these formats at a low level. Most things seem to be about the great concepts it uses to do all sorts of stuff, but nothing seems to be structured in an understandable way such as *firstly 16 bits of ..., then 20 bits of ..., then 28 of ..., then the relocation table, then some instructions of which ... means ... etc.*

Also, I use C++.

Comment: Have you read the Wikipaedia page on elf (first hot on google for linux elf) and what detail is missing including from its links which include several specifications?

Comment: Not to discourage you, but if you are going to design a new programming language, the last thing you will need to worry is about executable formats, as those are handled by low level tools like the assembler and linker. Check LLVM, which can take you a long way towards executable generation.

Comment: First hit for "ELF specification": http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf

Comment: You can take a look at http://colinm.org/language_checklist.html anyway

Comment: Another vote for LLVM if you're going for the compiled executable route. You might also consider targetting the JVM (if you're more about the static languages) or Parrot VM (for dynamic) for a more portable means of running intermediate code, as both platforms are reasonably well documented and suitable for targetting with your own languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an article about how to create tiny/simple PE files for Windows:

http://www.phreedom.org/research/tinype/

That article links to a guide for creating tiny/simple ELF files for Linux:

http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

They both have lots of technical details about the file formats, and they both mention nasm and similar tools.  I think the best way for you to accomplish your goals is going to be to generate assembly code and have nasm or another assembler create your executables.

Comment: Actually, the instructions used by my interpreter are based on assembler, so that will work greatly. Also, these are probably the kind of articles I was looking for.